# how to get the translated taxonomy term programmatically?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have tried this

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
```

and this:

```
$term = i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms(taxonomy_term_load($tid));
```

Both return the default language (English) term

I am using D7.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$translated_term = i18n_taxonomy_term_get_translation($term, $langcode);
```

Also, a good place to look for more information: /sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n_taxonomy/i18n_taxonomy.module

Answer (score 2):

1. Create translation sets (taxonomy example)

To translate a string, you should use two functions, depending on which i18n mode you use:

Localize mode: i18n_string_translation_update()

```
<?php
  $result_translation = i18n_string_translation_update(
    array('taxonomy', 'term', $tid, 'name'), // Path where to store source and translation.
    $translated_string,
    $language,
    $source_string
  );
?>
```

Translate mode: i18n_translation_set_create()

```
<?php
  // 1. Load or create a translation set.
  $translation_set = ($source_term->i18n_tsid) ?
    i18n_translation_set_load($source_term->i18n_tsid) :
    i18n_translation_set_create('taxonomy_term', $vocabulary->machine_name);

      // 2. Add the full source term in this set.
  $translation_set->add_item($source_term, $source_term->language);

      // 3. Add the full translated term in this set.
  $translation_set->add_item($translated_term, $translated_term->language);
  $translation_set->save(TRUE);
?>
```

Strings for other contents and modules

When a module defines its own strings, it must use some additional functions to allow these string to be tracked and updated.

Define the textgroup by implementing `hook_i18n_string_info()`. This is how it looks (i18n_taxonomy module)

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_i18n_string_info()
 */
function i18n_taxonomy_i18n_string_info() {
  $groups['taxonomy'] = array(
    'title' => t('Taxonomy'),
    'description' => t('Vocabulary titles and term names for localizable vocabularies.'),
    'format' => FALSE, // This group doesn't have strings with format
    'list' => FALSE, // This group cannot list all strings
    'refresh callback' => 'i18n_taxonomy_i18n_string_refresh',
  );
  return $groups;
}
?>
```

Read more at: [Using the i18n API from other modules](https://drupal.org/node/1114010)

Related:

[How to associate programatically the translation of new term to the original existing term?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87506/how-to-associate-programatically-translated-term-to-original)

Answer (score 0):

i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms works on getting site language

please check
Home » Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Languages
to ensure the site language detection is working as you wanted

i got this done when site languages change on user language preference

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to rewrite the Finder menue display with localized tayonomy terms:

```
<?php
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$result = $query
->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
->propertyCondition('name', $display)
->propertyCondition('vid', 3) // Change this to Your ID!!
->execute();

$found_tid = array_shift($result['taxonomy_term'])->tid;
// print $found_tid;

$tid = $found_tid;
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$translated_term = i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms($term);
print $translated_term->name;
?>
```