# How to get the translated term name by tid?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, taxonomy-terms

I'm looking for a *working method* to **get the translated term name** by `tid`.

The following code returns the original term name *but* not the translation.

```
global $language;

$lang_name = $language->language; // en

$term_id = 788;

$term = i18n_taxonomy_term_get_translation($term_id, $lang_name);
```

[image: Example of a translated Taxonomy Term (German to English)]

Most examples provided in "[how to get the translated taxonomy term programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63965)" seem not work for Drupal 7.

Comment: i think the code should work but the first parameter should be a term object and not a term id...

Comment: @lenni **Unfortunately it does not to work.** Drupal returns the same object back.

Comment: [Here's how to do it with Drupal 8.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/197453/27135)

Answer (score 17):

I managed to make it work! This is my code

```
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree(9); // Your taxonomy id

foreach ($tree as $term) {
  if (module_exists('i18n_taxonomy')) { //To not break your site if module is not installed
    $term = i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms($term); // The important part!
  }
  print l($term->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid); //print the terms
}
```

That sould do it! Diadeuf!

Answer (score 12):

You should use the i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms() function. This is the working code for me:

```
$tid = 10;
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$translated_term = i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms($term);
print $translated_term->name;
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem with localized taxonomy term translations.
If you have your "Multilingual options" translation mode set to "Localize", then it's pretty straightforward.

Let's say your term id is 788 like the OP's, then just do something along these lines:

```
  $i18n_object = i18n_get_object('taxonomy_term', 788);
  $target_langcode = 'de';
  $translated_term = $i18n_object->localize($target_langcode);
```

Comment: It worked for me!, weird that the function i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms didn't. thx

Comment: Worked perfect. Like @Namari function i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms didn't seem to do its job.

Answer (score 1):

Knibals code shows how to translate a full vocabulary tree. This code snippet shows how to translate one specific term.

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$translated_term = i18n_taxonomy_term_get_translation($term, $langcode);
```

This question was already answered here: [how to get the translated taxonomy term programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63965/how-to-get-the-translated-taxonomy-term-programmatically/63977#63977)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it as Function..

```
function _get_term_name_translate($tid) {
  $term = i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms(taxonomy_term_load($tid));
  return $term->name;
}
```