# How to get the vocabulary terms for the current language

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

How do I programmatically get all the terms within a vocabulary for the current language?

This is a similar question to [Get translated term name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/79037/42023), but not for a single term, but for the entire tree.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:

1. Getting the current language, and
2. Getting the terms for the current language

---

## 1. Getting the current language

Use the global [`$language`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/language/7) variable and get its `language` property:

```
$language->language
```

## 2. Getting the terms for the current language

In theory, you'd use [`i18n_taxonomy_get_tree`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!i18n!i18n_taxonomy!i18n_taxonomy.module/function/i18n_taxonomy_get_tree/7), like so:

```
global $language;
$tree = i18n_taxonomy_get_tree(1, $language->language,0,NULL,FALSE);
```

but it seems that function is [buggy](https://www.drupal.org/node/1249936). Instead, you can try using [`i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21i18n%21i18n_taxonomy%21i18n_taxonomy.module/function/i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms/7) with [`taxonomy_get_tree`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7) instead:

```
if (module_exists('i18n_taxonomy')) { // Check if the module exists
    global $language;
    $tree = i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms(taxonomy_get_tree($VID,0,NULL,FALSE));
} else {
    $tree = taxonomy_get_tree($VID,0,NULL,FALSE);
}
```