# How to get the original term name from the translation of a term without knowing the tid?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have a vocabulary which has the option `Localize. Terms are common for all languages, but their name and description may be localized.` set for its multilingual settings.

I have 2 languages on the site. One is `English` and 2nd is `Dutch`.
I have a term name `English term` and its translation in dutch is `Dutch term`.

So is it possible programmatically to get the original term name (English term) from the translated term name (Dutch term) ***without knowing the `tid`***?

In the question "[How to get the translated term name by tid?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79037)" the `tid` is known but here I mentioned that without knowing the `tid`. So this is a different question.

Any suggestions?

Comment: in that ticket the tid is know. And here I mentioned that without knowing the tid. so its not a duplicate.

Comment: Each term (whether translated or not) should have its own Term ID. You just need to use the taxonomy and i18n api to get it:
`$term_name = 'Dutch term';`
`$term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term_name);`
`$default_lang = i18n_string_source_language();`
`$en_term_tid = i18n_taxonomy_translation_term_tid($term->tid, $default_lang);`
`$en_term = taxonomy_term_load($en_term_tid);`