# When using Entity Translation and the Title module, how can I get the translated term from the term ID programmatically?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have a term ID and I want to programmatically get the translated term name (via Entity Translation and the Title module) for the logged-in user's language.  How can I do this?

[This similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63965/how-to-get-the-translated-taxonomy-term-programmatically) asks about how to get the translated name programmatically when using i18n taxonomy translation (the other major approach besides Entity Translation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this without circumventing the core API would be:

```
$tid = 322; // put here your term id
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$langcode = $GLOBALS['user']->language;
$translated_term = $term->name_field[$langcode][0]['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using [this module that extends EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.org/project/efq_extra_field)

After installing it, you are able to extend [EntityFieldQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) in the following way:

```
global $language;

$langcode = $language->language; // current site language
$tid = 322; // put here your term id

$query = new EntityFieldQueryExtraFields();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'your_vocabulary_machine_name')
      ->entityCondition('entity_id', $tid, '=')
      ->addExtraField('name_field', 'value', 'value')
      ->fieldLanguageCondition('name_field', $langcode, '=');

$results = $query->execute();

if (isset($results['taxonomy_term'])) {
  $translated_term = $results['taxonomy_term'][$tid]->extraFields->name_field_value;
  // do what you want with $translated_term
}
```

Hope this help.

MXT

Answer (score 0):

@plach's answer should technically work, but it has two problems:

1. It unnecessarily handles the language.
2. It's using an unsafe value, which is a security risk.

I recommend to instead use [field_get_items()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7) along with the safe value.

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$titles = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'name_field');
if (!is_array($titles) || !isset($titles[0]) || !isset($titles[0]['safe_value'])) {
  $term_translated = 'Invalid or untranslated taxonomy term / tag!';
}
$term_translated = $titles[0]['safe_value'];
```