# Get translated taxonomy terms with Entity Translation

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm using [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) for Taxonomy Terms.

I've a Cities Vocabulary and I need to get translated names of some 1600 cities.

Using [taxonomy_get_tree](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7) without arguments returns the term names in English. However if I pass the last parameter $load_entities= TRUE then it currectly returns $term->name as translated one.

But it seems fully loading 1600 terms by setting $load_entities can slown down the site performance heavily as mentioned in the api page.

**Is there any faster way to do it?**

I'm thinking of caching the results in a temp file. Or can use some query as in [When using Entity Translation and the Title module, how can I get the translated term from the term ID programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87229/when-using-entity-translation-and-the-title-module-how-can-i-get-the-translated) to fetch it myself.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Entity Translation, so keep in mind there can't be any translated term load because you're translating fields not whole term. Term will load by

`$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);`

use in devel mode or by dpm see the `$term` object. There you'll see structure

```
$term->name_field['en'][0]['value']
```

You can fetch it this way or by `field_get_items()` for en language.

```
$name = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'name_field', 'en');
```

AND

```
$term->name_field['fr'][0]['value']
```

You can fetch it this way or by `field_get_items()` for fr language.

```
$name = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'name_field', 'fr');
```

This is how you can get the data per language

Comment: Thanks but isn't this very slow for 1600 terms? This is what exactly I asked.

Comment: Then using entityFieldQuery would be good. Read https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708