# Localized Taxonomy terms in a View

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Localized taxonomy terms are not displayed in a View. Only the default language term is shown. I solved this issue writing a small module according to [this article](http://ggordan.com/post/localising-taxonomy-terms-in-views.html).

Perfect. But in one View i have two `fields: term ID` and `Global PHP code`. My question is: what needs to be changed in the Global PHP code below to have the localized terms displayed?

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($data->tid);
//print l($term->name,"voices", array('query' => array('type' => $term->tid)));
print l($term->name,"voices", array('query' => array('f[0]' => 'field_production_type_:'.$term->tid), 'attributes' => array('class' => array($term->name))));

/*
  $url = drupal_get_path_alias('taxonomy/term/'. $term->tid);
  $url_part = explode('/', $url);
  print l($term->name ,"voices/voiceovers/".$url_part[1], array('attributes' => array('class' => array($term->name))));
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question details provided, I'm not sure if the [i18nviews](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews) module is enabled (make sure it is).

Probably the best option might be to use `i18n_taxonomy_term_get_translation` as explained also in the questions:

- [How to get the translated term name by tid?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79037/get-translated-term-name).
- [how to get the translated taxonomy term programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63965/how-to-get-the-translated-taxonomy-term-programmatically)

Something else you may want to try to get the terms translated, is to use the setting (for Translation mode) `Translate. Different terms will be allowed for each language and they can be translated` (instead of 'Localize'). This setting can be found within `admin/structure/taxonomy/<YourTaxonomy>/edit`.

Comment: I do have i18nviews enabled. Without the custom module it only shows the term in the default language. I can imagine i need to change the code above with lines like: localized_term or localized_name but i don't know exactly which lines. Some suggestions for that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$translated_term = i18n_taxonomy_term_get_translation($term, $langcode);

Comment: Thanks a lot Namari, I replaced the first line of my code with yours: first line: $term = taxonomy_term_load($data->tid); into Your lines: $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid); $translated_term = i18n_taxonomy_term_get_translation($term, $langcode); But this didn't work out. I tried changing ($tid) into ($data->tid) then only the default language terms where displayed like before. Maybe i did something wrong. Would you mind to have another quick look at it and paste the complete piece of code?

Comment: try this:
global $language;
$lang_name = $language->language; //or use the one you want 'en', 'fr'...
$term = taxonomy_term_load($data->tid);
$translated_term = i18n_taxonomy_term_get_translation($term, $lang_name);

Comment: if it doesn't have a look here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79037/get-translated-term-name