# Translate taxonomy term programmatically

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

How can I translate a taxonomy term programmatically in drupal 8?
I found [how to get the translated taxonomy term programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63965/how-to-get-the-translated-taxonomy-term-programmatically) but this is only related to d7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In D8 you can translate entities with `addTranslation()`.

This is an example for a taxonomy term:

```
$term->addTranslation($langcode, [
  'name' => 'translated term',
])->save();
```

You can provide values for all translatable fields in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Based on using the i18n API from other modules, the code should be the following one.

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid); 
$translated = i18n_string_translate("taxonomy:term:$tid:name", $term->name);
```